# Angularjs and google chart api : chart type is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am developing a web application (Angularjs-J2EE). On the homepage I am showing a chart.
When i hit this homepage for the first time after I have started my server (Tomcat) I am getting this error :

> Chart not displayed due to error: The chart type is not defined.. Full
>   error object follows. ng-google-chart.js:197 Object {id:
>   "google-visualization-errors-0", message: "The chart type is not
>   defined."}

If I refresh the homepage, I don't have this error anymore. The chart displays well.
If anybody knows why...

Thanks.

Controller:

```
$scope.chartObject = {type:"PieChart"};
var datas = CaNetPieChart.query(function(){
  $scope.chartObject.data = {"cols": [
          {id: "t", label: "Article", type: "string"},
          {id: "s", label: "Colis", type: "number"}
      ], "rows": [
          {c: [
              {v: "CA Net"},
              {v: datas[0].valeur},
          ]},
          {c: [
              {v: "CA Net N-1"},
              {v: datas[1].valeur}
          ]}
      ]};
      $scope.chartObject.type = "PieChart";
      $scope.chartObject.options = {
          'backgroundColor': '#f5f5f5',
          'title': "Comparaison CA et CA N-1" ,'height':"200"  
      }
});
```

and HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-6" >
    <div google-chart chart="chartObject" style="{{chart.cssStyle}}"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

let try with this code.

```
$scope.loanchart = function(){
    $scope.chartObject = {};

    $scope.chartObject.data = {"cols": [
        {id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string"},
        {id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number"}
    ], "rows": [
        {c: [
            {v: "Mushrooms"},
            {v: 3},
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Olives"},
            {v: 31}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Zucchini"},
            {v: 5},
        ]}
    ]};
    $scope.chartObject.type = "PieChart";
    $scope.chartObject.options = {
        'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night'
    };
  };
```